# How to take input from a command and use it in another c# discord with dsharpplus

Tags: c#, string, discord, dsharp+

I have a Discord Bot for tournament info. I want it to take input from a command like !newtourneyinfo INFOHERE and then use INFOHERE as a string and use it in !tourneyinfo. I'm using DSharpPlus, here's some code that doesn't work, but my best shot as a newbie:

```
    string tourneyinfo;
    [Command("newtourneyinfo")]
    public async Task newtourneyinfo(CommandContext ctx, string newinfo)
    {
        await ctx.RespondAsync($"!tourneyinfo will now output {newinfo}!");
        newinfo = tourneyinfo;
    }

    [Command("tourneyinfo")]
    public async Task tourneyinfo(CommandContext ctx)
    {
        await ctx.RespondAsync($"{tourneyinfo}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that you are setting the *parameter* equal to an uninitialized variable outside of the method. When you write `newinfo = tourneyinfo`, `newinfo` is equal to INFOHERE or whatever argument was passed. Meanwhile, `tourneyinfo` is an empty string variable. What you probably want to be doing is setting `tourneyinfo` equal to the contents of `newinfo`.

In other words, try `tourneyinfo = newinfo` instead of `newinfo = tourneyinfo`.